# Php Doctrine OneToMany error : Undefined index in BasicEntityPersister.php

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, annotations

Hie there, after having past many times searching how I should have made an error, I have to ask now the question to the community since it is still a mystery.

I have here two tables : Solution and Project.
A solution can own N projects. A project can also be attached to no solution at all.

Here is part of the Solution.php file

```
/**
 * Description of Solution
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="X\Project\Repository\SolutionRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="solution")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *
 * @author michel.strasser
 */

class Solution
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * [...]
     */

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="X\Project\Entity\Project", mappedBy="solution")
     */
    private $projects;

    /**
     * [...]
     */
}
```

Here is part of the Project.php file :

```
<?php

namespace X\Project\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use DateTime;

/**
 * Description of Project
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="X\Project\Repository\ProjectRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="project")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *
 */

class Project
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \X\Project\Entity\Solution
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="X\Project\Entity\Solution", inversedBy="projects")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="solution", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */

    private $solution;
}
```

I've got the following error :
**Notice: Undefined index: solution in [...]\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister.php on line 1768**

... when I try to access to $solution->getProjects()->toArray();

Any suggestion ? Please.

Comment: I had a very similar issue. Turns out it was a typo in the mappedBy column.

Answer (score 0):

Bug found.

In fact there was no bug, I had to :

- launch the 3 orm:clear-cache-* doctrine commands
- delete the content of data/DoctrineModule/cache